# unable to compile code using gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

actually i have a project based on angularjs what i need to do that compile the code and create the folders using gulp.

/*Error*  => [12:03:39] Using gulpfile E:\projects\public\public\gulpfile.js                                                         [12:03:39] Starting 'mkdir:tmp'...                                                                                      [12:03:39] Starting 'config'...                                                                                         [12:03:39] Finished 'config' after 9.6 ms                                                                               [12:03:39] 'mkdir:tmp' errored after 23 ms                                                                              [12:03:39] Error: Command failed: rm -rf E:\projects\public\public/tmp && mkdir -p E:\projects\public\public/tmp        'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                              operable program or batch file.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)                                                                   at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)                                                                                           at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)                                                                                  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)                                                                        at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:334:11)                                                                at emitOne (events.js:96:13)                                                                                            at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)                                                                                        at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12) */

and when i am using del instead of rm command then process is not completing

/* Gulpfile.js */

```
gulp.task('default', ['build']);

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function(done) {   /* gulp watch */
    var debug = [].concat(settings.css)
        .concat(settings.js.filter(x => {
            return !x.match(/node_modules/)
        }))
        .concat(['./app/js/**/*.js'])
        .concat(['./app/views/*.html', './app/views/**/*.html', './app/views/**/**/*.html']);

    //console.log(debug);

    gulp.watch(debug, ['build']);
})

gulp.task('config', function() {       /* gulp config */


    var constants = {
        "Constants": {
            "baseUrl": process.env.baseUrl || "https://localhost:3005",
            "language": process.env.language || "en"
        }
    }
    ngConstant({
        name: 'app.constants',
        wrap: false,
        constants: constants,
        stream: true
    }).pipe(rename('app.constants.js')).pipe(gulp.dest('tmp/js'));

});

gulp.task('build', ['indexPage'], function(done) { /* gulp build */
    exec(`rm -rf ${__dirname}/dist && mv ${__dirname}/tmp ${__dirname}/dist`, function(err, stdOut, stdErr) {
        if (done && (err || stdErr)) return (done(err || stdErr));
        if (done) done();
    });
})

gulp.task('indexPage', ['js', 'css'], function(done) {

    var sources = [];
    if (settings.mode === 'development') {
        sources = sources.concat(settings.css).concat(['./tmp/js/app-vendor.js', './tmp/js/core.js', './tmp/js/*.js', './tmp/js/**/*.js', './tmp/js/**/**/*.js']);
    } else {
        sources = sources.concat('./tmp/css/style.css');
    }


    gulp.src(settings.index)
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(sources), {
            relative: false,
            transform: function(filepath) {
                filepath = filepath.replace('/app/', '/').replace('/tmp/', '/');
                switch (path.extname(filepath)) {
                    case '.css':
                        return `<link rel="stylesheet" href=".${filepath}?v=${+new Date()}">`;
                        break;
                    case '.js':
                        return `<script src=".${filepath}?v=${+new Date()}"></script>`;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return inject.transform.apply(inject.transform, arguments);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'))
        .on('end', done);
})

gulp.task('mkdir:tmp', function(done) {
    exec(`rm -rf ${__dirname}/tmp && mkdir -p ${__dirname}/tmp`, function(err, stdOut, stdErr) {
        if (done && (err || stdErr)) return (done(err || stdErr));
        if (done) done();
    });
});


gulp.task('js', ['mkdir:tmp', 'config'], function(done) {
    if (settings.mode === 'development') {
        gulp.src(['./app/js/*.js', './app/js/**/*.js', './app/js/**/**/*.js'])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js'))
            .on('end', function() {
                gulp.src(settings.js.filter(function(x) {
                        return x.match(/node_modules/)
                    }))
                    .pipe(concat('app-vendor.js'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js'))
                    .on('end', function() {
                        gulp.src(['./app/views/*.html', './app/views/**/*.html', './app/views/**/**/*.html'])
                            .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/app/views'))
                            .on('end', done);
                    })
            });
        return;
    }
})

gulp.task('css', ['mkdir:tmp', 'fonts', 'images'], function(done) {

    if (settings.mode === 'development') {
        gulp.src(settings.css)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/css'))
            .on('end', done);
        return;
    }

    gulp.src(settings.css)
        //.pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(uglifycss({
            "maxLineLen": 0,
            "uglyComments": true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/css'))
        .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('fonts', ['mkdir:tmp'], function(cb) {
    gulp.src(['./app/fonts/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/fonts'))
        .on('end', cb)
});

gulp.task('images', ['mkdir:tmp'], function(cb) {
    gulp.src(['./app/images/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/images'))
        .on('end', cb)
});
```

Comment: Hi @Kamesh, please try using "Git Bash Here" on the project folder, mostly this will fix the issue.

Comment: I have checked in git bash 

When i am using done() instead of * exec(`rm -rf ${__dirname}/tmp && mkdir -p ${__dirname}/tmp`, function(err, stdOut, stdErr) {
        if (done && (err || stdErr)) return (done(err || stdErr));
        if (done) done();
    });* then it's working fine, but we need to like this